# Modify pointer size of LLVM bitcode

Tags: c, command-line, llvm

I have a bitcode file I generated from another process. This file is guaranteed to be 64 bit, but I would like to convert the bitcode into 32 bit so I can compile it into a 32 bit application with clang or gcc.

I know LLVM does have a function capable of modifying the byte size of all pointers in bitcode, but [it is private](https://llvm.org/doxygen/DataLayout_8cpp_source.html#l00524) and only used when the DataLayout is being reset. There was also a `setPointerSize` function [publicly exposed](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/llvm/+/release_16/lib/Transforms/Utils/CloneModule.cpp#32) cerca version 1.6. I would like to know if there was a way I could modify the pointer size of llvm bitcode regardless of whatever else the program is doing.

I would prefer to use the command line but I could use the LLVM-C API if needed. I would also prefer to keep the bitcode in a binary format and not convert it to and from the text format LLVM IR. Thank you to anyone that has experience in modifying the DataLayout of bitcode and can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, or more likely not.

The (only) way to do it is to create a new Module with the [data layout](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html) you want, loop over the [globals (both functions and global variables)](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a8b8c3d18ad3b46fc0f8e34c72b4bcf1c) in the old module, and create equivalent globals in the new.

But that may not work. Examining C's sizeof may help understanding why.

There is a way to implement `sizeof Foo` in IR: You cast the integer 0 to a pointer to an array of Foo, then take the address of entry number 1 in that array, then cast the address to integer. This gives you the size of the first entry of the array (entry number 0), which is sizeof Foo (with some padding you may or may not want). There is another way to implement it by querying the DataLayout, and it is simpler and in my opinion also more tasteful.

You cannot rely on that other process to always use the cast-plus-address-cast process, so when you see the constant 32 in the module you're processing, you have a problem.

- Is that, say, the size of a struct that contains only pointers, in which case you should change it to 16?
- Or is it the size of another struct, one that contains half pointers and half values, in which case you should change it to 24?
- Or is it a 32 in the source code? Perhaps the source code implements a specification that allows strings to be up to 32 characters long?
- Or is it a 32 that was in a header file, and if the compiler had compiled for a different target it would have read a different header file and there'd have been a different value?

There are other similar issues. I think handling these integer constants is the biggest, but it's not the only issue.